# How can i pass variables from jenkins file to terraform

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, terraform

when i run terraform with local variables inside variable.tf everything work like a charm
i want to pass Jenkins parameters inside terraform variable.tf file so it will be dynamic from Jenkins
how can i achieve it?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }
    environment {
       TF_VAR_datacenter="${DATA_CENTER}"
       TF_VAR_cluster="${CLUSTER}"
       TF_VAR_esxi="${ESXI}"
       TF_VAR_datastore="${DATASTORE}"
       TF_VAR_network="${NETWORK}"
       TF_VAR_server_hostname="${SERVER_HOSTNAME}"
       TF_VAR_server_mac="${SERVER_MAC}"
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'DATA_CENTER', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'vcenter data center',)
        string(name: 'CLUSTER', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'data center cluster',)
        string(name: 'ESXI', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'esxi hostname',)
        string(name: 'DATASTORE', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'data center datastore',)
        string(name: 'NETWORK', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'data center network',)
        string(name: 'SERVER_HOSTNAME', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'server hostname',)
        string(name: 'SERVER_MAC', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'server mac',)
        string(name: 'SERVER_IP', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'server ip',)
        string(name: 'SERVER_NETMASK', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'server netmask',)
        string(name: 'SERVER_GATEWAY', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'server gateway',)
        string(name: 'COBBLER_PROFILE', defaultValue: 'xxx', description: 'cobbler profile',)
        choice(name: 'BUILD_DESTROY', description: '', choices: ['build' , 'destroy'])
    }

    stages {
        stage('OS PROVISION') {
            steps {
                dir("/root/terraform"){
                    sh """
                    export TF_VAR_datacenter=${DATA_CENTER}
                    export TF_VAR_cluster=${CLUSTER}
                    export TF_VAR_esxi=${ESXI}
                    export TF_VAR_datastore=${DATASTORE}
                    export TF_VAR_network=${NETWORK}
                    export TF_VAR_server_hostname=${SERVER_HOSTNAME}
                    export TF_VAR_server_mac=${SERVER_MAC}
                    terraform init
                    terraform apply -auto-approve
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
         always {
             echo 'This will always run'
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your example should work fine, but using the `-var` argument to the CLI would probably be easier.

Comment: When using environment block, you no longer need to export it again. It's duplicated. Btw, I don't get your issue. Your example didn't  work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer use this format:

```
terraform apply \
  -var 'vpc_id=$(AWS_VPC_ID)' \
  -var 'subnet_id=$(AWS_SUBNET_ID)' \
  -var 'aws_region=$(AWS_REGION)' \
  -var 'ami_id=$(AMI_ID)'\
  -var 'instance_type=$(AWS_EC2_TYPE)' \
  -var 'key_pair=$(KEY_PAIR_NAME)' \
  -var 'tags={ "Owner":"$(OWNER)", "Service":"$(SERVICE)", "Terraform":"true", "Env":"$(ENV)" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs a bit more clarity, but I am going to make a few educated guesses.

> with local variables inside variable.tf

Do you mean `locals {`, or what exactly do you mean by local variables?

> pass Jenkins parameters inside terraform variable.tf file

This isn't the right file to 'pass parameters'. `*.tf` files are for declaring variables.
You are probably looking at `*.tfvars` files.

You have 3 options with `*.tfvars` files:

1. a file named exactly `terraform.tfvars`
2. a file named `<anything>.auto.tfvars`
3. a file named `<anything>.tfvars` which you reference using the `-var-file` CLI parameter.

The format of `*.tfvars` files is simply:
`var1_name = var1_value`

You can (must) use the usual HCL markup fo trings, lists, maps, ...

Comment: i gave up and passed it from the -var option

Comment: If you show me your code, I can help you figure out what the issue is.